# Где получить информацию по управляющим последовательностям символов в C#?

Tags: c#, синтаксис, объявление

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где получить информацию по escape-последовательностям в C#?

А именно, хочу узнать, почему символ '\n' идентичен "\r\n", возможно '\n' является вызовом свойства `Environment.NewLine`? Например: `Console.WriteLine("qwe\nrty")`; выведет букву r под буквой q, хотя тут нет символа \r. Почему так происходит?

Comment: почему вы думаете, что они вообще в каком-то файле?

Comment: Хочу узнать, почему символ '\n' идентичен "\r\n", возможно '\n' является вызовом свойства Environment.NewLine?

Comment: @tym32167 откуда-то С# знает об их существовании

Comment: `\n` и `\r\n` - это разные варианты окончания строк. C# тут вообще не при чем

Comment: [Environment.NewLine Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) `A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.`

Comment: Очевидно, что последовательности "\n" и "\r\n" не идентичны, что и приносит много боли в мир кроссплатформенности. Они нигде не объявлены, .NET работает с ними как есть.

Comment: Например: Console.WriteLine("qwe\nrty");  выведет букву r под буквой q, хотя тут нет символа \r.  Почему так происходит?

Comment: [Перевод строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape-последовательности определены в спецификации языка C# ([ссылка на скачивание](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)).

Список всех используемых последовательностей приведен в пункте §2.4.4.4 «Character literals». Также можно посмотреть в C# Programming Guide на сайте Microsoft ([String Escape Sequences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/index#string-escape-sequences)).

```
┌────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────┐
│ Последовательность │                   Наименование                    │ Код Unicode  │
├────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────┤
│ \'                 │ Одинарная кавычка                                 │ 0x0027       │
│ \"                 │ Двойная кавычка                                   │ 0x0022       │
│ \\                 │ Обратная косая черта                              │ 0x005C       │
│ \0                 │ Null                                              │ 0x0000       │
│ \a                 │ Предупреждение (bell)                             │ 0x0007       │
│ \b                 │ Backspace                                         │ 0x0008       │
│ \f                 │ Разрыв формы                                      │ 0x000C       │
│ \n                 │ Новая строка                                      │ 0x000A       │
│ \r                 │ Возврат каретки                                   │ 0x000D       │
│ \t                 │ Табуляция                                         │ 0x0009       │
│ \U                 │ Символы Юникод (суррогатные пары)                 │ \Unnnnnnnn   │
│ \u                 │ Символы Юникод                                    │ \u0041 = "A" │
│ \v                 │ Вертикальная табуляция                            │ 0x000B       │
│ \x                 │ Символ юникод (как "\u", но с переменной длиной). │ \x0041 = "A" │
└────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Как видно из таблицы `\r` и `\n` это разные символы. По [историческим причинам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F) в разных ОС используются разные комбинации символов для обозначения перевода строки. Например, в Windows используются оба символа (`\r\n`).

Тем не менее, многие программы (в данном случае консоль) распознают символ перевода строки (`\n`) даже если он используется без возврата каретки (`\r`).

Comment: Если консоль распозант '\n' без '\r' как перевод строки, можно ли писать memwtr.Write("byte [" + i + "]: " + i + '\n'); (экономия памяти на символе '\r') вместо memwtr.WriteLine("byte [" + i + "]: " + i);, или так лучше не делать?

byte[] storage = new byte[255];

MemoryStream memstrm = new MemoryStream(storage);
StreamWriter memwtr = new StreamWriter(memstrm);

Comment: @Alex_ Хорошим тоном считается использовать `Environment.NewLine` ввиду удобочитаемости и кроссплатформенности, экономия несущественна. Тем не менее, Вы можете попробовать сэкономить один байт, это зависит от того, как эти байты будут использоваться в дальнейшем. Отдельные программы под Windows могут неправильно интерпретировать `\n` без `\r`. В общем, проверяйте для Вашего конкретного случая.